Why does my uncertainty estimation not give the expected result?
I trained simple MNIST Handwritten Digit Classifier 10 classes. Where I have original test data and its corresponding 90 degree rotated version.
It gave me expected result for number zero and one. Subjectively speaking, number zero is still similar with its original as we rotated to 90 degree version while there is no such similar number for rotated version of number one because its shape like a horizontal line.

Here is the visualization where:

Green Point: Original Image (Correct Prediction)
Blue Point: Transposed Image (Correct Prediction)
Red/Orange: Incorrect Prediction


It's intuitively understand for number 0 and 1, but not for other numbers where the dominance is going to higher uncertainty and higher confidence as epoch increase with highly confidence and low uncertainty to predict incorrect classes.
Here is my formula that I used:
Inputs:

Let $\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{\text{samples}} \times n_{\text{classes}}}$ be the input matrix of predicted probabilities, where:

$n_{\text{samples}}$ is the number of samples.
$n_{\text{classes}}$ is the number of classes (i.e., the number of possible predictions per sample).
Each element $p_{i,j} \in [0, 1]$ represents the predicted probability for sample $i$ and class $j$, and for each $i$, we have $\sum_{j=1}^{n_{\text{classes}}} p_{i,j} = 1$.




Definitions:

Let $N = n_{\text{classes}}$ denote the number of classes.
Let $\text{inf} = -\log_2(\epsilon)$ (where $\epsilon$ is the smallest representable number for the input's data type)
For each sample $i$, define:

The maximum predicted probability $a_i = \max_j (p_{i,j})$.
The minimum predicted probability $b_i = \min_j (p_{i,j})$.




Confidence:
For each sample $i$, the confidence is defined as:
$$
c_i = \log_2(N - 1) - \log_2(N) - \log_2(1 - a_i)
$$
where $a_i = \max_j (p_{i,j})$ is the maximum predicted probability for sample $i$.
Specifically:
The confidence for each sample is normalized as:
$$
c_i' = \frac{c_i}{\inf}
$$
where $\inf$ is a large constant, representing the inverse of the smallest representable number of the data type, ensuring that the confidence is mapped to the range $[0, 1]$.

Uncertainty:
The uncertainty for each sample $i$ is defined as:
$$
u_i = -\log_2(N) - \log_2(b_i) - c_i
$$
where $b_i = \min_j (p_{i,j})$ is the minimum predicted probability for sample $i$, and $c_i$ is the confidence for sample $i$.
Specifically:
The uncertainty for each sample is normalized as:
$$
u_i' = \frac{u_i}{\inf}
$$
where $\inf$ is the same large constant used for normalizing the confidence.
Then, the uncertainty is transformed as:
$$
u_i'' = \frac{2^{u_i'} - 1}{2^{u_i'} + 1}
$$
This maps the uncertainty values to the range $[0, 1]$.

Outputs:

The output consists of two arrays:

Confidence array $\mathbf{c}$: A normalized confidence value for each sample, where $c_i' \in [0, 1]$.
Uncertainty array $\mathbf{u}$: A normalized uncertainty value for each sample, where $u_i'' \in [0, 1]$.



The final output is a matrix $\mathbf{output} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{\text{samples}} \times 2}$, where each row contains the normalized confidence and uncertainty values for each sample.
